# NRV（named return value） copy-constructor

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, copy-constructor, return-value-optimization, nrvo

Recently, I was reading "inside the object model of c++" and I while reading chapter 5 I came up with the following question:

Will the compiler process the NRVO even when the class has a copy constructor ?

Comment: In short, you're asking whether the presence of a non-trivial copy constructor (i.e., one that can have side-effects) can forbid the compiler from performing NRVO (which removes the copying)?

Comment: yes, i'm not sure the answer

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "No, it won't prevent it."

n3290 (C++11 draft), Book of 12, chapter 8, verse 31 (p284):

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects.

Answer (score 2):

RVO (or NRVO) is optimization that compiler *might* use to elide copies, i.e. prevent redundant copies being created. Your custom implementation of copy constructor can not prevent this optimization being applied.

Answer (score 0):

RVO is, more or less, creating the object in the other scope instead and using that object instead of the local one when reading or writing variables. This leads to just one object being created and no copy ctor being called at all, rendering whether you have declared it irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is "if trivial copy constructor will prevent nrvo",
My answer is no.
I use the case in the book"inside the c++ object model", let it print the address of the member in the foo function and in the main function, the result show that they are the same in release mode while different in debug mode without optimism, in vs2010.
Which means NRVO is not care about whether you have a nontrivial copy constructor or a trivial one.